# How to apply cgroup parent in docker swarm?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, cgroups

Docker swarm doesn't support cgroup_parent according to it's documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cgroup_parent
I need to set resource constrains for the whole set of docker containers running on a particular host(not just per container constrains). Running vanilla Docker(not in Swarm mode) allows to have cgroups parent provided:

```
docker run -it --rm --cgroup-parent=/climit-cgroup/ <<image-name>>
```

or if one uses docker compose file using `cgroup_parent`.

But running docker containers in swarm node doesn't provide this ability. What are possible solutions to this problem in scope of Docker Swarm? Is there a way to enforce the existing cgroup on current host's swarm node?

Comment: I have the same question. I fear that this feature is not available at all for Docker Swarm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying using cgroups at daemon level with systemd

File: /etc/systemd/system/dockerdaemon.slice

```
[Unit]
Description=Slice with MemoryLimit=800M for docker
Before=slices.target

[Slice]
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryLimit=800M
```

Change /etc/docker/daemon.json and added

```
"cgroup-parent": "dockerdaemon.slice"
```

Then

```
systemctl daemon-reload ; service docker restart
```

Then /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
Slice=dockerdaemon.slice
MemoryMax=800M

sudo systemctl status docker
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─docker.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-08-20 08:58:45 UTC; 1h 32min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 12718 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 17
   CGroup: /dockerdaemon.slice/docker.service
           └─12718 /usr/bin/dockerd
```

I also check

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/dockerdaemon.slice/docker.service# cat memory.limit_in_bytes 
838860800
```

So it seems like the daemon is picking up the cgroup, yet when I create containers that amount to more than 800M, docker does not prevent it.
Also docker system info still sees all the memory

So it seems to me that this is not working well or maybe I got something wrong